# ASP.net Dynamic Dropdown Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

This seems like a reasonably common question, however the equally common solutions don't appear to work. Essentially the required validation control of the drop-down menu isn't firing. The drop down is populated dynamically, the code that populates the drop-down is shown at the bottom of the page.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Event" runat="server"DataTextField="EventTime" ValidationGroup="DD"
    DataValueField="EventID" SelectMethod="GetEvents" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select..." Value="-1" /></asp:DropDownList>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldEvent" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Event" 
        Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="DD" InitialValue="-1" AutoPostback="true"
        ErrorMessage="Please select a time"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Code Behind:

```
   public IQueryable<Event> GetEvents([QueryString("bikeID")] int? bikeId)
    {
        var _db = new WLL.DAL.Context();
        IQueryable<Event> query = _db.Events;
        if (bikeId.HasValue && bikeId > 0)
        {
            query = query.Where(b => b.BikeID == bikeId);
        }
        else
        {
            query = null;
        }
        return query;
    }
```

Comment: What I have done for Kendo drop down is to do a manual validation after the change event of the drop down. I haven't used ASP.NET controls in a while, so I don't remember the exact syntax to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set InitialValue = "0" .This worked for me when -1 did not work.

Comment: @LiamFell - Accept it as an answer then.Better way to say a thank you.